# Inverse of a matrix whose elements are linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have a symmetric, invertible matrix $M$ and a set of real, scalar variables $x_1, ..., x_n$.

Every element of $M$ is a sparse linear combination of $x_1,...,x_n$ with finite coefficients. So for any $i=1,...,n$ each element of $M$ is order $O(x_i)$ or constant in $x_i$

Is it guaranteed that elements of $M^{-1}$ are either constant in $x_i$ or of order $O(x_i^{-1})$? and if not are there any obvious additional conditions such that this would be the case?

For context, in my application $M$ is a Jacobian matrix which arises in a sensitivity analysis problem. I want to be able to loosely quantify the effect of changes in the variables $x_1,...,x_n$ on the inverse $M^{-1}$.

I've tried manually computing the inverse, and trying to estimate the order digging in to the decomposition from Cayley-Hamilton. Both get prohibitively messy for my particular example, so I wondered if I'm unaware of something more abstract that would be helpful.